# how to check if a pymongo.cursor

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm having this error 'pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query' at cur_data = cur[0], and this is my code:

```
cur_list = list(cur)
if len(cur_list) == 0:
    print("empty")
else:
    cur_data = cur[0]
```

where cur is a pymongo.cursor.cursor

I've tried count() but it's depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are trying to do, but I would suggest chaning the last line:

```
cur_data = cur_list[0]
```